# Generate .sql script based on .csv file

Tags: c#, oracle, csv

I have for example this table:

```
table1.csv
    Item;Location;Oftr;OftrPost;Replen
    B01;BI1_p;40;01.05.2015;2
    B02;BI1_p;40;01.05.20
```

I want to generate a .sql external table script. Here's sample:

```
CREATE TABLE filename*
(
row* type*
row* type*
row* type*
) ORGANIZATION EXTERNAL (
TYPE ORACLE_LOADER
DEFAULT DIRECTORY dir_name*
ACCESS PARAMETERS (
RECORDS DELIMITED BY NEWLINE
SKIP 1
FIELDS TERMINATED BY delimiter*
MISSING FIELD VALUES ARE NULL
)
LOCATION(filename*)
)
reject limit unlimited;
```

filename, delimiter, dir_name and row won't be a problem (Few checboxes, readline, path.getiflename). Problem is type*.
Basically i'll be moving between 3/4 variables - float, number, varchar ,( date if i could do it)
Question is - How can recognize which column has numeric or float or varchar?
My first thought was REGEXP, but maybe someone has better idea.

Comment: This request doesn't make much sense. What will you do if the data for one of the columns is NULL in all rows? (meaning B01;;....  - this means the first value is B01, the second is NULL, ...). Also, you may have strings that contain only digits; for example, phone numbers should be stored as strings (VARCHAR2), not as numbers. Finally, if you have a date like 12-10-11, how are you going to interpret that? There are six different possible interpretations, all equally legitimate. Perhaps if you describe the higher-level problem you are trying to solve, we can think of better approaches.

Answer (score 1):

You could either define some Regex for int, float and date and if none of them matches, it's a varchar.  Or you could just use `int|double|DateTime.TryParse()` and also if none of them succeeds, treat it as a varchar.

But be aware to inspect not just the first line of your data, but some of them (better all of them if possible -- you'll have to parse them later anyway). Also make sure, you check for int before you check for double, because a `double.TryParse()` will return true also for an integer. And if you use Regex, make sure the regex for double can also accept integers, because you might have numbers without decimal places in a column that is supposed to be double.

Answer (score 0):

Just in case you're ok with a non-code solution, our SQL Developer IDE will do that for you. Point it to a CSV, it will generate the External Table or SQL*Loader scripts for you.

[image: To get started, right click on Tables node and say 'Import Data']

Step by step instructions [here](http://www.thatjeffsmith.com/archive/2012/08/using-oracle-sql-developer-to-setup-sqlloader-runs/)